# How to use implode() in sql operator?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-5.3

My problem is that i stock a variable (`id_chambre`) as an `array` in my `database` and i want to use it in `SQL` but it's not working :

```
$sql = "SELECT c.* 
FROM chambre AS c
LEFT JOIN reservation_client AS rc
  ON c.id = rc.id_chambre AND rc.start < '$en' AND rc.end > '$str' AND chek!=2
WHERE rc.id_chambre IS NULL";
```

in `SQL` it does not considered `id_chambre` as an array it apply the `SQL` test just in the first argument in the array.for example `id_chembre(1,5,9)` it takes just 1.

Comment: That is a bad SQL design. You should change it

Comment: @nacho sorry how i can fix it  ?